# C++ map versus multimap for multi-key lookup

Tags: c++, dictionary, multimap

My data conceptually looks like:

```
"BLUE" :  (3 , 10,  15, 1220,  44040)
"RED"  :  (44, 523,  122143,  323233)
"BANANA" : (....)
```

Build-time is not important.  For lookups where I have multiple keys,  where I want to combine all the value lists,  and sort them;   should I represent this as a map or a multimap in C++ for the fastest outcome?

In other words, since the value vectors attached to the keys are variable length, should I have a map with key:vector,  or multimap with key1:int1, key1:int2,  etc?

The aim is to write a function where input = (key1, ...., keyN)  and the output is a sorted list of all the values.

Answer (score 1):

The `map<string, vector<int>>` solution is easier to understand and code against, and probably more efficient, space-wise, since you're arranging groups of values into contiguous storage rather than creating a node for each value. For the same reason, it's probably also more efficient algorithmically.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be populating only once before doing any lookup, the best way is a vector that you sort after it's populated: `vector<pair<string, int> >`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you provide some more detail please?  Populating map or multimap?  Sorting the string-int pairs of the multimap? I'm a bit confused.